# Specify the language in a website

Tags: php, locale, silex, setlocale

how should I set the locale in my site? I mean, in a test for websites it says I'm not setting the language..

I tried with html this way:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="es">
```

but someone said is not the way, even the test still says the language was not set

Comment: use <html lang="es"> In w3c Using the meta element to specify the document-wide default language is obsolete. Consider specifying the language on the root element instead.

Answer (score 2):

Specify it in the HTML tag like this:

```
<html lang="es">
```

More information [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/NOTE-i18n-html-tech-lang-20070412/#ri20030112.213801634).

Answer (score 0):

If you want multilingual web site. Then you need Create a string array with values. And load by language prefix. When spanish You will load string es.php when english you will load string file en.php.